# Fixing multiple column in dataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables 1.10.0 and I need to fix some columns of the table as in the image.

[image: DataTable With Fixed Column]

As in the dataTables documentation for table with FixedColumns, I have tried the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#mytable').dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "ordering": false,
        "scrollY": "300px",
        "scrollX": "100%",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
    });
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( table );
});
```

This only fixes the S.No. column for the table in the image. How can I fix the first three columns from left, for my particular case S.No., Action and Status.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `leftColumns` parameter. See the [multiple fixed columns](https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/FixedColumns/examples/two_columns.html) example in the documentation.

```
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( table, {
    leftColumns: 3
} );
```